# When using ffmpeg "tpad" padding frames are green

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm not sure when this started happening to me, but I think it was with the advent of release 6.0, that when I use the "tpad" filter, like so:

```
-filter_complex "[0:0]tpad=start_duration=1:stop_duration=5:color=black[v0]" -map "[v0]"
```

the padded frames are green, regardless of what color I specify.  I've tried this with mp4's, mkv's and avi's, and have gotten the same results.  It's also been the same if I use the build from rpm-fusion-updates (6.0-11.fc38, libavfilter 9.3.100 / 9.8.101), or if I build it myself from the source (currently N-111066-gd26ea03f60, libavfilter 9.8.101 / 9.8.101).

It's happening on several different machines, too.  Is anyone else seeing this?  I'd like to confirm it's not just me before submitting a bug.  I'm not seeing one open for this.

Comment: Doesn't happen here, with 6.0. Does happen, with git master.

Comment: The regression happened on May 22, likely commit 86b252ea9d

Comment: Have you tried other syntax like `color=black` or even omitting `color` for leaving the black default.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same issue under Windows 10. Switching to the below version of Ubuntu - no problem, no green screen, the default black was applied automatically. So, such workaround works.

Description: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS,
Release: 20.04

Used Windows10 ffmpeg version: N-111283-g9b6d191a66-20230628

Used Ubuntu ffmpeg version: 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1

Regards - Pawel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The reason it does not happen with the Ubuntu version is that that is 4.2.7. The issue was introduced in [86b252ea9dee18006910e30646ad1067f2d1323f](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=86b252ea9dee18006910e30646ad1067f2d1323f), currently not present in any release.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression from FFmpeg commit [86b252ea9dee18006910e30646ad1067f2d1323f](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=86b252ea9dee18006910e30646ad1067f2d1323f) that I made a while ago. The bug report for this regression is at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/10621.

I've [submitted a fix for this](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2023-November/316718.html) to the mailing list and it will probably get merged soon.

You can work around the issue by specifying the `start` and/or `stop` option (depending which you need) with a dummy value like `1`, while still specifying the `start_duration` and/or `stop_duration`, which will take precedence.

So given your example above, the following should work around the issue:

```
-filter_complex "[0:0]tpad=start=1:start_duration=1:stop_duration=5:color=black[v0]" -map "[v0]"
```

(When both `start_duration` and `stop_duration` are used, just giving either `start` or `stop` with a dummy value is enough to make the broken check happy.)

Sorry for this regression!